# What feedback does the OP receive when there are multiple close reasons?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

As the fifth person to vote to close a question, I saw three different reasons given (too broad, unclear, homework). I agree with all of them, so I thought the OP would receive good feedback. When I looked at the question afterwards, however, the feedback was minimal:

> put on hold as off-topic by Tyberius, Zhe, Mithoron, Buttonwood, Karsten Theis 2 mins ago
>
> This question does not appear to be about chemistry within the scope defined in the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please edit the question.

Is there a reason why there is so little feedback (there are two different sites linked from the first and second occurrence of "help center"). I seem to remember seeing combinations of close reasons (maybe just two instead of three or four in this case). I used the "off-topic, fill in the blank" reason, so there was a comment from me as the only specific reason to close:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question lacks context. This question needs revision before it is ready for a great answer. Please edit to include how this question came up and how you tried to answer it. This will help writing an answer that is useful for you and for others. – Karsten Theis

My question is how does the software choose what to give as a close reason when more than one have been given?

Comment: No time to answer properly: majority reason is displayed. If that is a 'fill in the blank', the default template (as in the question) is displayed. When it is a custom close reason (like homework) the names of the voters is also displayed.

Comment: Adding to what Martin said, there's several questions about this on meta.stackexchange.com, including, iirc, feature requests to display all chosen close reasons, not just the majority.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason